# How do I change the RGB colour of objects in GIMP?

Tags: colors, gimp, layers

Some background: I am attempting to do some web design as a hobby. I am now at the point where I want to start introducing some texture to the site, and [Tileables](http://tileabl.es/) seems useful.

The readme in the Tileable packs states:

> In this pack you should find a layered PSD file which contains each of the patterns in this pack on their own layer. I've included this so you can edit each pattern to your liking before defining a new pattern. You should also find the PAT pattern file which you should import into Photoshop. This is done via the layer styles menu when looking at the pattern overlay options. Finally, you have individual PNG tiles of the patterns so you can start using them in other applications.

I don't have Photoshop, so I downloaded GIMP (version 2.6.11). I have used neither before. I can't open the PAT file (error message: GIMP pattern plug-In could not open image), but I can open the layered PSD file. This gives me each Tileable as a layer.

The following step is to change the Tileable to match a colour in my palette. The colour I want to use is #f9efde, and its RGB value is 249, 239, 222. I have tried to play around in GIMP (specifically with the functions in the "Color" menu, such as "Color Balance", but this function seems to give me only the option of setting the percentage composition of colours in terms of the RGB and CMYK models. Where can I set the RGB value?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Till some one post the right answer, see this if this could help you

- [How to change color of an object in gimp](http://www.spotht.com/2010/10/how-to-change-your-car-color-in-gimp.html)
- [Making a Seamless Background Image](http://www.awardsites.com/tutorials/gimp/smlsbkg01.htm)

and i would like to suggest you, if you need tile pattern you should check some online tile generators.they are handy and easy to use for newcomers....

- [15 online background generator](http://singlefunction.com/15-online-background-generators/)
- [Bg patterns](http://bgpatterns.com/)
- [Stripe generator](http://www.stripegenerator.com/)

And the most usefull tool for edit PSD online

- [pixlr](http://pixlr.com/editor/)

  you can use this and complete your project without any hassle

Comment: Thanks Jack, this has been really helpful, especially BgPatterns. I actually managed to add some great texture to the site with that. I would still, however, like to know how to change the RGB colour of objects in GIMP (for my own understanding).

Comment: have you tried the online psd editing tool,this one can solve your problem

Comment: i guess the first link in this answer shows something related to the same...

Comment: You are right on both accounts; I'll be experimenting! I'll let you know.

Comment: hope to see your success....